# Drop All Foreign Keys TO Specific Table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one table on postgres db, lets call it "table1", that must be moved to other database. But in this database has also other tables referencing to "table1" through the column and foreign key "table1_id". So my issue is **I want to keep the column table1_id, but drop the FK from each table**.

**The problem is a lot of tables references this "table1", so it would take time to check one by one and drop the constraint.**

How could I list and drop all foreign keys to "table1" in my database and drop it without perform a one-by-one drop? Is that possible?

Comment: Get the constraints from the dictionary, form a dynamic SQL statement dropping them and execute that for each of them.

Comment: can it be done only using sql?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bad idea, you loose referential integrity. At some point you will get rows in the child tables which no longer have appropriate rows in the parent table. But, if you are OK with that, it is a fairly process.  
A two step process is required:

1. Use information schema views table_constraints and
   referential_constraints to generate the necessary DML.
2. Execute the generated statements.

The following accomplishes step 1.

```
select 'alter table ' || tcc.table_name || ' drop constraint ' || rc.constraint_name 
  from information_schema.table_constraints tcp 
  join information_schema.referential_constraints rc
    on (rc.unique_constraint_name = tcp.constraint_name)
  join information_schema.table_constraints tcc
    on (tcc.constraint_name = rc.constraint_name)
 where tcp.table_name = <place table name here>;
```

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree with you about the data consistency. But it is part of an microsservice ecosystem, so actually the data consistency is ensured by other layers. This table move is one of a lot of actions that we will need to do to keep the consistency.

Comment: "*the data consistency is ensured by other layers*" - believe, it's not. Doing this in the database is the only 100% safe way to do it

Comment: of course, nothing is better than have everything in same database. But it is a common issue when working with microsservices and the other layers should lower the risk (aka fail tolerance). It's a start step when thinking in split entities in a entire ecosystem, but lot of things will be done later.